# GWT how can I modify the button value in the ClickHandler

Tags: gwt

I want to implement this function, when I click on the button, the value of the button changes. But I know I cannot call the button object itself in its clickHandler. So, How can I do this?

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                    button.getButtonElement().setValue("X");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why you cannot call the button inside its handler?

Comment: By the way, you can simply do button.setText() instead of calling its element.

Comment: the point is I am adding handler to the button, I can not call the button at the same time.

Comment: Of course you can: button.setText("X");

Comment: Your Button variable should simply be declared as `final` i.e. `final Button button = ...;` and then it's definitely possible to use it in click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

```
((Button)event.getSource()).setValue("x");
```

Or

Outside the handler, use

```
final Button btn = button;
```

Then you will be able to use btn as reference to the button inside the handler .

Comment: Thanks for solutions. I used the third way: </br> <code>new ClickListener(){</br>public void onClick(Widget sender){}</br>}</code>

Comment: @Jie `ClickListener` is deprecated. You are encouraged to use `event.getSource()`, but it is all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very easy problem to solve:

```
final Button b = new Button("Old text here", new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    b.setText("new text here");
  }
});
```