# GWT - how to set and get the value attribute of a Button()

Tags: gwt

I've got a Button element and i would like to set and then get the value attribute of this button.

Currently rendered:

```
<button type="button" class="gwt-Button">page 1</button>
```

What I want to achieve:

```
<button type="button" class="gwt-Button" value="1">page 1</button>
```

Code:

```
final Button b = new Button("page 1");
// HOW TO: set value for the button
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // HOW TO: get value for the button
    }
});
```

[Documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html) says nothing about this and the answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831765) doesn't even compile ("The method setValue(String) is undefined for the type Button")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure about this but you could try to access the underlying button element itself and modify/read the value from there. Like:

```
button.getElement().<ButtonElement>cast().setValue("1");
```

See more:

- http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html
- http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/ButtonElement.html